# Why does path's iterator return "\\" while traversing?

Tags: c++, c++17

I am using a new and modern C++17 with the filesystem API. I am working in Windows, with Visual Studio 2017.

The following code gives an unexpected result:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <filesystem>

int main()
{
  std::filesystem::path path(R"(D:\dir\file.cpp)");
  for (auto& dir : path)
  {
    std::cout<<dir<<std::endl;
  }
}
```

Result is:

```
"D:"
"\\"
"dir"
"file.cpp"
```

Why was "\\" printed?

Testing this in GCC 9.1.0 (please change '\' to '/' in the path variable), the result is:

```
"D:"
"dir"
"file.cpp"
```

Why is the behavior different?

Which result is correct according to the C++17 standard?

Comment: Probably because it separates directory name (D:) from full root path (D:\\)

Comment: I guess, `D:` is a root name, "\\" is a root directory separator according to docs: "...a directory separator that, if present, marks this path as absolute. If it is missing (and the first element other than the root name is a file name), then the path is relative and requires another path as the starting location to resolve to a file name.". https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/path . By the way: `path.root_directory()` also returns `"\\"`

Comment: "\" is the root directory and I guess the result you get is correct because `std::filesystem::path` has already a function called: `root_directory` which will return `"\"` as well. Also: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/path/begin. I would say GCC is the wrong one.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file#fully-qualified-vs-relative-paths for some information on windows path names.

The C++ standard has this to say about path iterators ([[fs.path.itr]/4](http://eel.is/c++draft/fs.class.path#fs.path.itr)):

> For the elements of the pathname in the generic format, the forward traversal order is as follows:
>
> - The [root-name](http://eel.is/c++draft/fs.class.path#nt:root-name) element, if present.
> - The [root-directory](http://eel.is/c++draft/fs.class.path#nt:root-directory) element, if present. [ Note: The generic format is required to ensure lexicographical comparison works correctly. — end note]
> - Each successive [filename](http://eel.is/c++draft/fs.class.path#nt:filename) element, if present.
> - An empty element, if a trailing non-root [directory-separator](http://eel.is/c++draft/fs.class.path#nt:directory-separator) is present.

On windows, the path `D:\dir\file.cpp` has a disk designator of `D:`, followed by the root directory on that disk, `\`, then the path of `dir`, `file.cpp`. According to windows, `D:` is a root-name, so `\` is a root-directory. You could have `D:dir\file.cpp`, but note that this is now a relative path.

On gcc, if not on windows, `D:` will be treated as a regular directory name (The same as `./D:/dir/file.cpp`). So, there is no root-name or root-directory. If you had instead had `/D:/dir/file.cpp`, the iterator would have contained `/`, `D:`, `dir`, `file.cpp`.